# SWT - GridData Layout

Tags: java, layout, swt

I have a method that creates 4 buttons.  The buttons sit next to each other from left to right.

```
|-[b1] [b2] [b3] [b4]-----------------| <- edge of dialog
```

I want to be able to have a empty space in between b2 and b3

```
|-[b1] [b2]-----------------[b3] [b4]-| <- edge of dialog
```

Changed the layout to

```
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(6, false);
```

But I not sure how to get the space between the buttons.  Can you assign a button to a specific grid number in the layout?

```
b1 = 1
b2 = 2
b3 = 5
b4 = 6
```

Comment: You can assign empty string Labels in 3 and 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Layout` is filled one slot at a time from the upper left to the lower right. Thus, you cannot "skip" slots. **But**, as already mentioned by Gilbert in the comments, you can fill the "unused" slots with empty labels:

```
Button buttonOne = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH); // 1. slot
Button buttonOne = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH); // 2. slot

new Label(parent, SWT.NONE)  // 3. slot
new Label(parent, SWT.NONE)  // 4. slot

Button buttonThree = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH); // 5. slot
Button buttonFour = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH); // 6. slot
```

Note, that you don't *have* to assign them (`Label labelOne = ...`), since you are not going to use them.

---

It might be a good idea to force equal spacing of all columns, i.e. using:

```
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(6, true);
```

instead of

```
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(6, false);
```

Otherwise it might be necessary to assign a `GridData` (to fill horizontally) to the dummy `Label`s.

---

In other scenarios, it might also be of interest to use [`horizontalSpan`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/GridData.html#horizontalSpan) of [`GridData`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/GridData.html):

```
Button button = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
data.horizontalSpan = 2;
button.setLayoutData(data);
```

In this case, the button will take up 2 slots of you layout.